# How can I collect money fast in Mytown?

Tags: ios, mytown

I spend a lot of time waiting for the next collection, anybody has a good idea?

Comment: Is this an iPhone game that paces itself to bend your schedule to the game? Those games are designed to have no 'fast way' to do anything, otherwise they couldn't pace themselves and gently carrot their way into your schedule.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure how the game mechanics work exactly but you could try changing the date on your iDevice to as far as you need to collect money. If that doesn't work, the game runs off of internet time and you are out of luck. You are just going to have to wait it out.